# Socket entre 2 dispositivos

Tags: java, socket

Gostaria de enviar dados entre maquinas diferentes, entre 2 computadores, entre um computador e um *Android* por exemplo.

Fiz o exemplo internamente, no mesmo computador, mas quando separo (o servidor fica em um computador e o cliente vai para outro. Não dá certo).

**Servidor:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Instancia o ServerSocket ouvindo a porta 12345
            ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12345);
            System.out.println("Servidor ouvindo a porta 12345");
           // servidor.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.5.1", 0));

            InetAddress inet = servidor.getInetAddress();
            System.out.println("HostAddress="+inet.getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("HostName="+inet.getHostName());
            while(true) {
              // o método accept() bloqueia a execução até que
              // o servidor receba um pedido de conexão
              Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
              System.out.println("Cliente conectado: " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
              ObjectOutputStream saida = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
              saida.flush();
              saida.writeObject(new Date());
              saida.close();
              cliente.close();
            }  
        }   
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Cliente:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             Socket cliente = new Socket("0.0.0.0",12345);
            InetAddress inet = cliente.getInetAddress();
            System.out.println("HostAddress="+inet.getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("HostName="+inet.getHostName());
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            Date data_atual = (Date)entrada.readObject();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data recebida do servidor:" + data_atual.toString());
            entrada.close();
            System.out.println("Conexão encerrada");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

O estranho é que a saída do servidor é:

```
Servidor ouvindo a porta 12345
HostAddress=0.0.0.0
HostName=0.0.0.0
```

Aí quando tento colocar o cliente em outro computador não dá certo, mesmo inserindo (no cliente) o *IP* em que o servidor está.

**Obs.:** As máquinas estão em redes diferentes.

**Obs².:** Fiz teste mesmo com o *firewall* do *Windows* desativado e não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

No cliente você precisa passar o endereço IP ou hostname do servidor.

```
Socket cliente = new Socket("0.0.0.0",12345);  // <<< errado
```

Não conheço Java, mas a linha acima deveria ser

```
Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12345);  // <<< mesma máquina
```

ou

```
Socket cliente = new Socket("10.172.36.130",12345);  // <<< outra máquina
```

onde "10.172.36.130" é só um exemplo, você precisa substituir pelo IP (ou nome) da máquina onde seu servidor está rodando.

Comment: Eu tinha substituido pelo ip da máquina onde o servidor está mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o output do servidor:

O output está correto, como você não especificou qual IP era pra dar bind, ele deu bind em todos da interface de rede.

Sobre o código:

```
Socket cliente = new Socket("0.0.0.0",12345);
```

Eu apenas alterei o "0.0.0.0" para o IP do meu servidor remoto e o código funcionou corretamente. Você deve estar com algum bloqueio de firewall.